# getting "User" is not accessedPylance - error notification

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, sqlalchemy, notifications, pylance

I have installed python 3.9.7 64-bit in Windows 10 - I am using VSCode editor- installed flask, flask-login, flask-sqlalchemy using pip install command line. I created **models.py** with below commands

```
from .import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

# Defined Class note#
class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

#defined class User#
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

Then created Python file ****init**.py** to get the data values. but due to the pylance notification, unable to create the database.db file after running the below command.

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from os import path
    
    db = SQLAlchemy()
    DB_NAME = "database.db"
    
    
    def create_app():
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'gjkagfkag khsgfafhl'
        app.config['SQLQLCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
        db.init_app(app)
    
        from.views import views
        from.auth import auth
    
        app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
        app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
    
        from.models import User,Note (**# this line is Getting notification highlighter** -(class)user and (class) Note is not accessed Pylance)
    
        
        create_database(app)
    
        return app

def create_database(app):
     if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app = app)
        print('Created Database!')
```

Screen shot:
[Notification from pylance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vxCp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem with this message. In fact, is not an Error message, it's more like a Info message.

Pylance is telling you that you have imported the User class, but you're not using it. Therefore, User is not accessed. If you hover your cursor over the Note import, the same message will appear and for all variables and imports that you are not using it.

Bonus: Your app config is wrong at the "SQLQLCHEMY_DATABASE_URI". I believe that is "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI".